# Excel Formula - RANK Dates by Employee Number

Tags: excel

I have table with employees and dates. Some of the emps are Duplicates in their column ("E") and can have more than on row in the table. Every row has date in column "W". I want to find a way to rank every row of employee by latest date.

for example:

```
empNum Date
112311 12/10/2016
112311 11/09/2015
122311 06/08/2018
144533 23/03/2012
144533 01/11/2018

first row rank = 2
second row rank = 1
third row rank = 3
fourth row rank = 1 
fitth row rank = 2
```

Comment: sort by employee number, then by date...

Comment: I want to calculate in new column for another formula...

Comment: Then improve your question so we can understand what you want, show the initial situation and then the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cell A1 has the value `empNum` and the data is continuous, the following formula should help:

`=RANK.EQ(B2,$B$2:$B$4,1)`

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-rank.eq-function

> The Excel RANK.EQ function returns the rank of a number against a list
>   of other other numeric values.

You might want to specify what we need to do about `empNum`, rather provide an example with 5 rows containing 2 distinct `empNum`

Comment: In the column of the emp number, I have many emps in that column. I want to rank for each emp its dates.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking each employee's dates within that employee's group of dates is a simple matter if you consider what the RANK is actually accomplishing; specifically the rank is the number of dates that are less than or equal to any one date for any one employee. COUNTIFS can do that.

```
=countifs(a:a, a2, b:b, "<="&b2)
```

I'm guessing that the *122311* was a typo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Begme.png)

Answer (score 0):

### "Ranking within a group"

What you are searching for is "Ranking within a group". There can be multiple ways to achieve the same:

Method 1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$6=A2)*(B2>$B$2:$B$6))+1
```

Method 2:
as mentioned by @user10981853

```
=countifs(a:a, a2, b:b, "<="&b2)
```

[Discussion thread to same problem](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/543546-rank-within-group-within-sub-group-problem.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your "rank" seems to be the number of Dates for the same Employee Number that are equal to the row, plus 1, so this should work:

```
=1+COUNTIFS(A:A,A2, B:B, "<" & B2)
```

Do note that if you have rows with the same data, these will both have the same number, and you will have a "gap", like so: (observe that there are two `6`s, one `8`, and no `7`)

```
EmpID | Year | Rank
 007  | 1962 |  1 
 007  | 1963 |  2
 007  | 1965 |  4
 007  | 1964 |  3
 007  | 1967 |  6
 007  | 1969 |  8
 007  | 1967 |  6
```